# android 5.0 lollipop long touch animation (spreading out)

Tags: android, listview

I would like to replicate the following style of animation on touch of an item in a listview

you can see the touch animation here: http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/11/android-50-lollipop-animation-100529875-orig.gif
please excuse the link, I dont have enough reputation for embedding an image.

the animation should spread out from the moment there is a touch event until it is recognized as a long click where it then turns into a select.

If anybody can help me with this or redirect me to the correct place to find an answer for this would be great.

thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ripple animation, set you app theme as Material or AppCompat (with support library v7 rev 21 min) and create a ripple drawable in XML or Java.
[This tutorial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/ripples-part-1/) explain how to do this.

For the touch event you can set an OnClickListener or OnLongPressListener